# Simplify Hypergeometric2F1 that algebraically should cancel

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, algebraic-manipulation

I have a probability mass function that should sum to unity algebraically, but neither `FullSimplify` nor `FunctionExpand` can deal with the `Hypergeometric2F1` therein.

```
myPMF[x_, p_, k_] := (   p^k *(1 - p)^(x - k) 
                      + (1 - p)^k * p^(x - k)  ) Binomial[ x - 1, k - 1] // Simplify    
(*  coin toss that ends when either k heads or k  tails appears ;
    x = total number of flips;
    k <= x <= 2 k  
*)

Assuming[ 0 < p < 1, Element[x | n, Integers]
   Sum[ myPMF[x, p, n], {x, n, 2 n - 1}] // FullSimplify 
 ]    (* expecting exact 1 like the numerical verification below ;
        FunctionExpand basically does nothing to HyperGeometric *)

start = 16; stop = 40; (* this takes maybe 6 seconds *)
Table[
       Sum[ myPMF[x, p, n], {x, n, 2 n - 1} ]
 , {n, start, stop} ] // Simplify
```

The exact sum can be done with partial numerical inputs as the code shows.

How do I carry out the algebraic sum and arrive at unity? Perhaps a different way of using `FunctionExpand`?

Thank you.

Comment: Your function can be simplified to `2 - (BetaRegularized[1 - p, n, n] + BetaRegularized[p, n, n])`.

Comment: @J.M. This is interesting. Thanks. Are you suggesting that I define my probability mass function with BetaRegularized to begin with, or that I can manipulate the current form with built-in commands into the BetaRegularized version? If the latter, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Nono, your PMF is as it should be, but its form was the tip-off that the summation would involve the regularized incomplete beta function at some point. Admittedly, *Mathematica* had to be helped a bit here; I'll write a detailed answer later, but if you want to try things out yourself in the meantime, the [Pfaff transformation](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/16/01/01/0001/) is particularly useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the "no thinking needed" way to demonstrate this:

```
FunctionExpand[DifferenceRootReduce[
               Sum[(p^n (1 - p)^(x - n) + (1 - p)^n p^(x - n)) Binomial[x - 1, n - 1],
                   {x, n, 2 n - 1}] // FunctionExpand, n]]
   1
```

---

If, like me, you felt that that was unsatisfactory, here is a way that requires one to assist *Mathematica* in a few places, with the guidance of knowing a few hypergeometric identities.

For reference, this is the expression we get from directly evaluating the sum:

```
expr = Sum[(p^n (1 - p)^(x - n) + (1 - p)^n p^(x - n)) Binomial[x - 1, n - 1],
           {x, n, 2 n - 1}] // Simplify
   2 - ((1 - p) p)^n Binomial[2 n - 1, n - 1]
       (Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2 n, 1 + n, 1 - p] + Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2 n, 1 + n, p])
```

As I had noted in the comments, the [Pfaff transformation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E1) is one of the first things to try; making this replacement gives

```
expr /. Hypergeometric2F1[a_, b_, c_, z_] :>
        (1 - z)^(c - a - b) Hypergeometric2F1[c - a, c - b, c, z] // FullSimplify
   2 - n (Beta[1 - p, n, n] + Beta[p, n, n]) Binomial[2 n - 1, n - 1]
```

where we now encounter the incomplete beta function. (Alternatively, one could use [this identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/03/0006/).) A further simplification can be done using the identity

```
n Binomial[2 n - 1, n - 1] == 1/Beta[n, n] // FullSimplify
```

which yields

```
2 - (Beta[1 - p, n, n] + Beta[p, n, n])/Beta[n, n]
```

(or alternatively, `2 - (BetaRegularized[1 - p, n, n] + BetaRegularized[p, n, n])`).

Finally, one can use the [reflection formula for the incomplete beta function](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/17/02/03/0001/) to get the desired result.